# Absolutely positioned div over a p causes links in the p to not be clickable

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned div over a p, and it causes links in the p to not be clickable, and none of the text is selectable either.

The div doesn't have any background, just a border.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `z-index` of the `<div>`. That should drop it behind the `<p>`

Comment: Yeah but then it won't be much of an overlay because it will hide behind the `<p>` :)

Comment: He said the `<div>` just has a border and no background. I would imagine that it's probably engulfing more than just the `<p>` and that's maybe why he's doing it this way. I'm thinking that it's okay if the `<div>` is behind the `<p>`, but we'll see when the OP comes back :P

Comment: That's right, I'm just trying to get a border of a specific size around some elements.  I tried setting the z-index of the p to 5 and the z-index of the div to 0, but that didn't work.  However, if I set the z-index of the div to -1, then it works.  Any idea why I have to set it negative?

Comment: That's generally what I've seen used. Imagine the z-index coming out of the screen with positive being towards you and negative being into the screen.

Comment: I figured out why `z-index:5` on the p didn't work. I had to also set `position:relative`.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it, what if you had some links inside the `overlay` div? The browser gives focus to the topmost element (highest z-index), so all the elements within it can be clicked and the text can be selected.

Think of another solution and ditch the absolutely positioned div.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the css styles of the top . It will no longer be clickable and will let mouse events pass through it to

Comment: This is the "cleanest" solution in that you don't have to mess with `z-index` or anything, but note that it's not supported in IE at all...

Comment: I didn't know... good to know as it's important on a project that I'm working on right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you place a piece of paper over another piece of paper. The one below can no longer be touched - this is by design.

Why don't you put the DIV below the P instead, and give the P a transparent background?